# Set a floating div's width to take up remaining space

Tags: html, css

I would like to make display-field divs to take up the whole remaining width. Now the display-field width is equal to text length. How to do that?

```css
.display-label {
        float:left;
        clear:left;
        min-width:160px;
}

.display-field {
        float:left;
        clear:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="display-label">Account Id</div>
<div class="display-field">30221</div>
<div class="display-label">Full Name</div>
<div class="display-field">Tomas</div>
```

Comment: i think u want this http://tinkerbin.com/V7vfbkY8

Comment: That won't work if the content of the label div is wider than 160px.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove float and clear from `.display-field`. Now the .display-field div starts from the left side of the browser so you need to add the desired colors to the divs to manipulate the output.

```
.display-label {
        float:left;
        clear:left;
        min-width:160px; 
        background:white
}

.display-field {
    background:red
}​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WKBu5/5/)

Comment: You will have some trouble applying the same padding to the fields if the width of the labels vary.

Comment: this is a visually fix, the `.display-field` is actually behind `.display-label`.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow:hidden;` is your friend here.

```
   .display-label {
        float:left;         
        clear:left;         
        min-width:160px;
    }  
    .display-field {        
        overflow:hidden;
        background:#ccc;    
    }
```

[jsfiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamessouth/bhqVM/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this.

```
.display-label {
        float:left;
        clear:left;
        min-width:30%;
        background: red;
}

.display-field {
        float:left;
        clear:right;
        background: yellow;
        min-width:70%;
}
```

[see live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mack28/mKUH6/)

Adjust `min-width` as per your need.

Hope it will helps you. Thanks !!